# How to access enum values from jstl foreach to jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, jstl

I have a tricky question and need some help. In `SomeEnum`, I have id, name and icon as parameters.

In html I have a table like this:

```
<%  pageContext.setAttribute("itemEnum", SomeEnum.values()); %> 
<table id="item_table">    
<c:forEach var="entry" items="${itemEnum}">
    <tr class="item" id="${entry.name}">
        <td><c:out value="${entry.id}"/></td>
    </tr>
</c:forEach>
</table>
```

In my jquery, I need to get icon and name for each enum object and update row value accordingly.

```
$("#button").click(function(){
    $('#item_table tr').each(function(item, i) {
    var name = ?? 
    var icon = ??
    });
});
```

How? Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

From what you've given us it isn't clear where "icon" is coming from.  However, I'll offer omething I do on a regular basis and see if it solves your problem.

```
<%  pageContext.setAttribute("itemEnum", SomeEnum.values()); %> 
<table id="item_table">    
<c:forEach var="entry" items="${itemEnum}">
    <tr class="item" id="${entry.name}" data-name="${entry.name}" data-icon="${entry.icon}">
        <td><c:out value="${entry.id}"/></td>
    </tr>
</c:forEach>
</table>
```

Then in your jQuery you can do this:

```
$("#button").click(function(){
    $('#item_table tr').each(function(item, i) {
        var name = $(this).attr("data-name");  // could also be $(this).data("name");
        var icon = $(this).attr("data-icon"); // could also be $(this).data("icon");
    });
});
```